# Book with parallel world where books live as people and there is a tree growing bookmarks on it

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember a story with a young woman who lives (maybe not all the time) in a big old house in England that is described like an English "Manor". Her little sister/brother is sometimes with her but is kidnapped at some point in the story  (?).

She goes to a parallel world where people are figures from books or books itself. She has a (living, running or flying) book herself which enables her superpowers or doing magic. One portal to this world is a big real world bridge.

In this world is a forest, where dead books are buried and are seeds for the trees. At some point the young woman is living or hiding in some tree houses with a lot of other people. (20-50?)

Also there is a house of glass where there stands a tree on which all bookmarks would grow. I remember a big ship made of paper. And one female person's torso is able to be opened like a book, so she wears a corsage to avoid this. It was not usual in this world.

I think I read it as a real book, but I also read a lot of e-books. It would be in the last 5 years and it was an actual book I think. It was in German language.

The ship is one of those traditional ships with big wheels on the Mississippi. The young woman and her magic book somehow make it fly.

It is possible to travel via book in the real world. One needs two books of exactly the same year, printing and so on. One could teleport from one of these to the other and then they are destroyed.

Comment: It sounds like the author had helped themselves to the laudanum

Comment: In which stage? The early to promote or the late to destroy creativity?

Comment: The stage where you've had to much and the world goes all floopy while you're writing :-)

Comment: I do not know, if I get it right :( but I have (rare but) best memories with this book ^^ So I think this world is not floppy... :)

Comment: Hi Allerleirauh. I've made some minor edits to change what I suspect were translation errors. If you don't like the changes I've made please feel free to roll them back. Can you remember if it was a German author, i.e. the book was originally in German, or whether it was originally in another language and translated into German?

Comment: @JohnRennie The meaning do not have changed :) There is a high possibility, that it is a German author. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the book today by accident. I took an interesting book out of the library's shelf and it was the second one in the series.

[image: Cover of the book "Die Seiten der Welt"]

It is "Die Seiten der Welt" ("The Pages of the World" or also "The Sides of the World") by [Kai Meyer](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kai_Meyer), a german author.

The main character's name is Furia. There are 5 books of this series. And [here](https://kaimeyer.com/connect/die-seiten-der-welt/) you can find the German homepage of the series with a lots of interesting artwork, i.e. the ship made of paper :)

Comment: Is there an English translation available?

Comment: Thanks for coming back years later and posting an answer!

Comment: @Shawn Seems not to have an english translation :( See [good reads website](https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/41320525-die-seiten-der-welt) for the translations. But there seem to be a graphic novell. Maybe you have more luck with this.

Comment: I am sorry, there is no graphic novelle. I was mislead by a comment on the authors website about the graphic work he saw and chose the artist for the pictures in his books.